# ArcGIS rectify image with embedded colormap (clr)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, geotiff-tiff

When rectifying a georeferenced tif image in ArcMap 10.2 the colormap gets placed into an accompanying .clr file. Is there a way to stop this behaviour and have it embedded into the tif so it is usable in other applications? Alternatively is there a tool I can use to combine them afterwards?

Comment: It explains here and it can be found here :[How to Export Raster with same classification colors seen in ArcMap?]


  [1]: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57464/how-to-export-raster-with-same-classification-colors-seen-in-arcmap